# Make Chrome app run with special window borders

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Here is my current `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My App",
  "description": "My App Description",
  "author": "My Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://www.example.com"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://www.example.com",
      "container": "panel",
      "height": 500,
      "width": 500
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "app128.png"
  },
  "permissions": []
}
```

What's happening: the app opens in a `500x500px` window with system borders.

What I need: the app needs to open with the Chrome-style borders. (The same as the Google Keep app, or if you don't have the Google Keep app, go to the App Launcher => Hamburger Button => Settings)

What do I need to change in, or add to, my `manifest.json` file? Thank you!

**Screenshot of what I'm getting vs. what I need:**
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, did you want your app to look like Google Keep?

Comment: @BenWells For the window borders, yes.

Comment: What system are you on? My "Hello World" on Chrome OS has chrome-style borders by default, and my Google Keep doesn't have the _hamburger button => settings_ you mention.

Comment: My Chrome Dev Editor runs your sample without a problem, in a window with borders identical to my Google Keep.

Comment: @CodyHess I clarified that sentence. I'm on Windows 8, and the above code produces a window with system borders, unlike the Keep app. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: To get a border like Google Keep or the other packaged apps you mention you will need to create a packaged app (the manifest given is for a hosted app). See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps for more details. Also see https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window for details on window creation and frame options.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm largely ignorant of the nuances distinguishing a [hosted app](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide), a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), and a [packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps), I have a *suspicion* that your "hosted" app uses the system borders of its "host" OS, and rewriting as a "Chrome" app would give you the same Chrome-style borders as Google Keep.

Please try this rewrite; I'm very curious to see if it works: (you'll have to use a `<webview>`)

#### manifest.json

```
{
  // name, description, manifest_version, etc
  // NOT "launch"
  "app": { "background": { "scripts": ["main.js"] } },
  "permissions": ["webview"]
}
```

#### main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("webview-embedder.html");
});
```

#### webview-embedder.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
  <body><webview src="http://www.example.com"></webview></body>
</html>
```

I'll be so pumped if this works :-p.

Comment: This answer is correct. I don't know why it has been marked down.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is by adding 'frame':'none' to your window options when creating your window in background.js.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create("frameless_window.html",
    {  frame: "none",
       id: "framelessWinID",
       innerBounds: {
         width: 360,
         height: 300,
         left: 600,
         minWidth: 220,
         minHeight: 220
      }
    }
  );
});
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window

Answer (score 0):

Please try following CSS change to apply the red border to the frameless chrome-app:

```
html,body {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```